# Hiding the ellipsis button (more button) in CommandBar in UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: uwp, ellipsis, commandbar

I am using a commandbar in my project (UWP), however, I realized there is an ellipsis button in the commandbar by default. Is there any way where by I can hide/remove it?

[image: Ellipsis button]

Here's my code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar 
        Background="{StaticResource CitiKioskBackgroundBrush}"
        IsOpen="True"
        IsSticky="True"
        Name="appBarName"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        >
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="SettingAppBarButton"
                      Icon="Setting"
                      Label="Settings" 
                      Foreground="White" Click="SettingAppBarButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `OverflowButtonVisibility` property:

`<CommandBar OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed"></CommandBar>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I have tried the codes, and it shows a XBF syntax error '0x09C4' :Property Not Found. Why is that so?

Comment: @thalassophile This property is introduced from `Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (introduced v10.0.14393.0)`. Please make sure that your project's min version is 14393 and target version is 14393 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no property to disable the `MoreButton` of the [`CommandBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx), you'll have to copy the [`CommandBar` template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx), remove the `MoreButton` element from it, and apply the template to your `CommandBar` instance. Eventually, you have to modify further parts of the template to make it function correctly.